# mvvm with prism: setting view from menu item

Tags: wpf, data-binding, prism, icommand

I am new to wpf world. I have a context menu in the shell as below:

```
              <ContextMenu>

                <MenuItem Header="Login" 
                          Command="{Binding WorkSpaceViewSetter}" CommandParameter="DemoApplication.View.LoginView">

                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <Image Height="16" Width="16" Stretch="Uniform" Source="/Images/login.png"/>
                    </MenuItem.Icon>

                </MenuItem>

                <MenuItem Header="Modules" ItemsSource="{Binding AppModules}">

                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <Image Source="/Images/modules.png"/>
                    </MenuItem.Icon>

                    <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding ModuleName}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding ElementName=win, Path=DataContext.WorkSpaceViewFromType}"/>  
                            <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding MainViewType}"/>                       
                        </Style>
                    </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>

                </MenuItem>

           </ContextMenu>
```

Each element in the itemssource `AppModules` of the Modules menuitem has a property named `MainViewType` of type `System.Type`. I want to change the view of a region when a menuitem gets clicked and am thinking of using a single `ICommad` in the `shellviewmodel` and passing the `MainViewType` as command parameter. However, the above code is not working.
I was wondering why then the `Modules` menuitem gets populated from the `itemssource` as expected.

I have noticed that the command binding on the `Login` menuitem is also not working even though it should have, since the `itemssource` property of `Modules` gets properly bounded. Can anybody please suggest how to make it work?

Comment: What does the ICommand's Execute look like?

Comment: I am using DelegateCommand<T> from Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Commands.

Answer (score 0):

Context menus aren't on the same visual tree as the rest of your window, so using ElementName in the binding won't work. You'll need to using `PlacementTarget` instead. Without knowing how your viewmodels are structured it's difficult to give a definitive answer but your solution will look something like:

```
<MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
      <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding ModuleName}"/>
      <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext.WorkSpaceViewFromType}"/>  
      <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding MainViewType}"/>                       
   </Style>
</MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
```